# Is there a way to get the information from MS unit test framework outside of the VS environment?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I created a test framework to test a sample application.  This basically required creating a Solution for my sample application and then adding a Native Test Project, which can test the application.

The test project generates an `.exe`, but if I were to execute the `.exe` on it's own, it does nothing.

Is there a way to get information from the test programme so it can be used for other purposes outside of the VS environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a couple of days, but I've found that DeJaVo's answer is incorrect.  Because I am running a **Native Test Project**, MSTest *will not work* with it.  To run a Native Test from the command line, use [`VSTest.Console`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run unit tests without VS2013.

Use [Run automated tests from the command line using MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487(v=vs.120).aspx) source to do so.

In general it says:

1. Open a Visual Studio command prompt.
2. Either change directory to your solution folder or, when you run the MSTest.exe program in step 3, specify a full or relative path to the metadata file or to the test container.
3. Run the MSTest.exe program.

I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: The info is great, it just doesn't work.  Get the following message:

Comment: `Unable to load the test container 'UnitTest1.dll' or one of its dependencies. If you build your test project assembly as a 64 bit assembly, it cannot be loaded. When you build your test project assembly, select "Any CPU" for the platform. To run your tests in 64 bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your tests in a 32 bit process. Error details: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\...\UnitTest1.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`

Comment: Did a dependency walk on it.  It couldn't find IESHIMS.DLL.  Found that in  my `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer` folder which I added to the path at the command line.  The others that it couldn't find are `API-MS-WIN-*.DLL` files (which I believe shouldn't matter as they are linked in differently IIRC) and `EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL` which I'm going to research now.

Comment: Looks like I was able to find all of the `API-MS-WIN-*.DLL` files.  They were on my machine in some obscure places.  However, I can't find `EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL`  Hmmmm.

Comment: As this is not your fault but M$'s, I'll just give it to you as it answers the question.  Thanks.

Comment: A new question has been posed here: [Cannot run MSTest on my unit test dll (VS2013)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614523/cannot-run-mstest-on-my-unit-test-dll-vs2013)